# SQL Server Cross Type Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two simple tables. One of which has businesses and one has users. I want to create a query that returns all business Ids for each user. So my tables are like this:

### Business

BusinessID

### User

UserID

If I have three businesses and two users, I want to get six records back

### BusinessID | UserID

```
1      |    1
2      |    1
3      |    1
1      |    2
2      |    2
3      |    2
```

I need something like a join without a join table. Please help and thanks ahead of time.

Comment: is relation between these tables is one to many or many to many?

Comment: Can you post the full schema for those tables?

Comment: and where the foreign key that relate these table with each other?

Comment: @Miroprocessor, @Mr. Jefferson: Why? All is writen in question.

Comment: This is a many to many. There is a table that relates the two but when the Users are System users, then we ignore the table and display all Businesses for each of those users. I didn't create the schema:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT B.BusinessID, U.UserID FROM tblBusiness AS B, tblUser AS U
```